# If a runtime exception was thrown after a resource was open - the program close the resource?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I wrote a simple java function that reads a file of Floating-point values and in the case file is not found or
the values that are being read are not floating-point the program throws exceptions.

My question is on the case that the program opened the file but the format of values was not floating-point - can the program close the resources? or should I consider the runtime exception that may happen?

```
 public static ArrayList<Double> readValues(String filename) throws 
    FileNotFoundException {

    var file = new File(filename);

    var fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
    var doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();


    //In case the values are not of double type and the scanner 

        while(fileScanner.hasNext()) 
            doubleList.add( Double.parseDouble( fileScanner.next() ) );


    fileScanner.close();
    return doubleList;
}
```

o.k I updated the code to use in 'finally' statement

```
    public static ArrayList<Double> readValues(String filename) throws 
    FileNotFoundException {

    var file = new File(filename);

    var fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
    var doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();


    //In case the values are not of double type and the scanner 
    try {
        while(fileScanner.hasNext()) 
            doubleList.add( Double.parseDouble( fileScanner.next() ) );
    }finally {
        fileScanner.close();
    }

    return doubleList;
}
```

If there are better ideas, I would like to know.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Close resources in finally block of try-catch-finally of try-finally because finally block always gets executed after try block regardless of exception being thrown or not

Comment: ok, but in case that I use the first program (the example). is it a mistake? or that by default we should not consider runtime-exceptions? thanks!

Comment: By default, we should consider the runtime exceptions, in your first code you are throwing FileNotFoundException, if NumberFormatException occurred, it's not caught and not able to throw, so the program stop with an exception.

Comment: When program closes it releases all the resources it holds. So if your program gets closed when it fails to read the file it would close the file too. So first example is ok. However, it is very preferable that you handle resources yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Java finally block is always executed whether exception is handled or not.

[Please refer to this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flow-control-in-try-catch-finally-in-java/)
A standard approch

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(...);
    // do something with the inputstream
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle an exception
} finally { //  finally blocks are guaranteed to be executed
    // close() can throw an IOException too, so we got to wrap that too
    try {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            fileInputStream.close();
        }        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle an exception, or often we just ignore it
    }
}
```

From java7: The try-with-resources Statement

From the oracle docs [Refer here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

You can close resources by using try with resources

```
try(// open resources here){
    // use resources
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // exception handling
}
// resources are closed as soon as try-catch block is executed.
```